# Differential equation solveable in $x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Examine the following differential equation for singular solution if any:

$ap^2 - 2py +4x=0$$\,$
where $p = {dy\over dx}$

I converted it to form of $4x = 2py-ap^2$. Then I differentiated it with respect to y and tried to factorise it but was not able to factor it, can someone tell me how to proceed further ?

Comment: Any of your steps? What did you manage to obtain?

Comment: @EgorIvanov will you please look again, i updated it

Comment: The $\dot{y}^2$ and the $y\dot{y}$ suggest that this can be written as the derivative of a linear differential equation.

Answer (score 1):

$$ap^2-2py+4x=0$$
First of all let's check what happens if $a=0$:
$$2y'y = 4x\Rightarrow(y^2)' = (2x^2)' \Rightarrow y^2 - (x\sqrt{2})^2 = C$$
So as integral curves we have hyperbolas, no singular solutions. Now let's suppose $a\ne 0$. We take partial derivative:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial p}\left(ap^2-2py+4x\right)=0$$
$$ap = y \Rightarrow p = \frac{y}{a}$$
Return to initial problem:
$$y^2= 4ax\Rightarrow y = \pm\sqrt{4ax}$$
Let's check if this curve is solution:
$$y' = \frac{\pm a}{\sqrt{ax}}$$
$$a\cdot\frac{a^2}{ax}-2\frac{a}{\sqrt{ax}}\sqrt{4ax}+4x=\frac{a^2}{x}-4a+4x=\frac{(2x-a)^2}{x}=0$$
There isn't any $a$ values such that this curve is even a solution.

Comment: The partial derivative with respect to $p$ seems incorrect, since $p = y'$. I suggest you check your work and, in particular, remember to use the chain rule.

Comment: @cpiegore No, here we think of $p$ as of independent variable

Comment: Yes, I understand what you are saying, but I'm not sure it really makes sense to do that, since $p = y'(x)$. I'm pointing this out because there seems to be a discrepancy between your answer and the other answer below, and I think this may be the reason why.

Comment: @cpiegore Look through the comment I have left under the solution below

Comment: And for what reason do we treat $p$ as an independent variable when $a \ne 0$ but not when $a = 0$.

Comment: @cpiegore Because we use division by $a$ in the solution, so it is easier to consider the case of $a=0$ separately, it comes out that in this case ODE can be solved explicitly and has no singular solution