Why p-discriminant method for finding singular solution does not produce the same singular solution as d'Alembert method?
I am learning the p-discriminant method for finding singular solutions for non-linear first order ODE's.
But in this example ode, which is d'Alembert ODE, when using standard d'Alembert method for finding singular solution, I do not get the same solutions as when using p-discriminant method.
The two singular solutions found using d'Alembert  are correct. The one found using p-discriminant does not match any of them and does not even verify the ODE. So in this example, this method failed to find the singular solutions to this ODE.
I thought that the p-discriminant method will always find singular solution (if they exist). This method is explained in number of places such as this math24.net ; here is small screen shot of the method from the above

I checked my steps and see nothing I am doing wrong. So I am confused about this result and looking for explanation.  Does this mean that p-discriminant method can fail to find singular solutions?
Solve
$$
y^{\prime}+x\left(  y^{\prime}\right)  ^{2}-y=0
$$
Finding singularities using standard dAlembert method of solving. Let
$p=y^{\prime}$ then the above becomes
$$
p+xp^{2}-y=0
$$
Solving for $y$ gives
\begin{equation}
y=xp^{2}+p \tag{1}
\end{equation}
Comparing the above to the standard d'Alembert ODE form
\begin{equation}
y=xf\left(  p\right)  +g\left(  p\right)  \tag{2}
\end{equation}
Show that $f\left(  p\right)  =p^{2},g\left(  p\right)  =p$. Taking
derivative of the above w.r.t $x$ gives
\begin{align}
y^{\prime}  &  =f+xf^{\prime}\frac{dp}{dx}+g^{\prime}\frac{dp}{dx}\nonumber\\
p  &  =f+xf^{\prime}\frac{dp}{dx}+g^{\prime}\frac{dp}{dx}\nonumber\\
p-f  &  =\left(  xf^{\prime}+g^{\prime}\right)  \frac{dp}{dx} \tag{3}%
\end{align}
But $f^{\prime}=2p,g^{\prime}=1$, the above now becomes
$$
p-p^{2}=\left(  2xp+1\right)  \frac{dp}{dx}
$$
The singular solution is when $\frac{dp}{dx}=0$ which means $p-p^{2}=0$ or
$p\left(  1-p\right)  =0$ or $p=1,p=0$. Substituting these into (1) gives the
two singular solutions
\begin{align}
y_{1} &  =x+1\tag{4}\\
y_{2} &  =0\nonumber
\end{align}
General solution is when $\frac{dp}{dx}\neq0$. This can be solved if needed
(not shown).
Now let's use the p-discriminant method to try to find the singular solutions
to the above ODE. This method is simple. We write the ODE as $F\left(
x,y,y^{\prime}\right)  =0$ then find $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y^{\prime}
}=0$ and eliminate $y^{\prime}$ and solve for $y$.
Writing the ODE as (using $p=y^{\prime}$)
\begin{equation}
F\left(  x,y,p\right)  =p+xp^{2}-y=0\tag{5}
\end{equation}
Then
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial F}{\partial p}  & =0\nonumber\\
1+2xp  & =0\tag{6}
\end{align}
Now we need to eliminate $p$ from (5,6). Eq. (6) gives $p=\frac{-1}{2x}$.
Substituting this in (5) gives the singular solutions. Eq (5) now becomes
\begin{align*}
\left(  \frac{-1}{2x}\right)  +x\left(  \frac{-1}{2x}\right)  ^{2}-y  & =0\\
\frac{-1}{2x}+x\left(  \frac{1}{4x^{2}}\right)  -y  & =0\\
-\frac{1}{4x}\left(  4xy+1\right)    & =0\\
\left(  4xy+1\right)    & =0\\
y_{s}  & =-\frac{1}{4x}
\end{align*}
But this is not in Eq. (4). This solution does not even satisfy the ODE. So the p-discriminant method failed to find the singular solutions.
Should not this method of finding singular solution(s) have produced same
solutions as the direct d'Alembert method? Why did it fail on this ODE?

The p-discriminant is singular for the differential equation, but not necessarily a solution itself. I think if that were the case you would have a Clairaut equation, after some variable change. The p-discriminant is just the points where a locally unique solution of $F$ for $p$ does not exist.

@LutzLehmann I am not sure I understand what you just said. by singular solution, I mean the envelope of the family of curves of the general solution. According to the page I linked to, and other references, they say p-discriminant can be used to find singular solutions to an ode. But you seem to say it means something else. And this is what is not clear to use. I do not understand exactly what you mean by The p-discriminant is singular for the differential equation, but not necessarily a solution itself.

Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4841548/differential-equation-solveable-in-x/4842412#4842412.

See this article of historical interest (1911)

As you observed, you get two types of singular. What you call singular solutions are not singular as solutions, these are members of the regular solution family of the equation that happen to be linear. On linear solutions $p=C$ is constant, and the equation then is
$$
y=f(C)x+(C),
$$
which has slope $f(C)$, so $C=f(C)$ needs to hold for these solutions by necessity.
But what is nice in quickly figuring out these solutions makes them singular when trying to parametrize solutions by $p$. All non-linear solutions have such a parametrization on segments where they are strictly convex or strictly concave in the $(x,y)$ plane. Similar to what you found, taking the derivative for $p$ and using $\dot y(p)=p\dot x(p)$ one gets
$$
(p-f(p))\dot x(p)=f'(p)x(p)+g'(p).
$$
This is a nice linear DE for $x$ that has the above linear solutions as singularities. After finding the solution for $x(p)$, the other component is simply $y(p)=f(p)x(p)+g(p)$ per the original differential equation.
The other type of singular points $(x,y)$ are the points where $y=f(p)x+(p)$ is not solvable for $p=\phi(x,y)$ according to the implicit function theorem. Or alternatively but the same, where the second differential equation
$$
p-f(p)=(xf'(p)+g'(p))p'(x)~~\text{or}
\\
y'(x)-f(y'(x))=(xf'(y'(x))+g'(y'(x)))y''(x)
$$
has a zero as coefficient of the highest order derivative. These points where $xf'(p)+'(p)=0$ do not belong to the domain where the given implicit DE can be made into one or multiple ODE.
These singular points form a set, usually a curve, in the $(x,p)$ plane, that can be lifted to $(x,y,p)$ space via the original DE and then projected to the $(x,y)$ plane (possibly with fold points or loops).
This curve can only be a solution if the left side above is also zero everywhere, that is, if $f(p)=p$ a function. This specializes the d'Alembert equation to a Clairaut equation. Note that for Clairaut equations, the regular solution family of lines is singular in the first sense. And indeed the singular curve in the second sense is also a solution, and is tangent to a regular line in every point.
